# How to execute some code whenever new access token is inserted in spring-security-oauth?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented Oauth2 using spring-security-oauth. I used password and refresh-token grant type.

The flow is user first presents username and password and after verification, authorization server provides refresh token.
Using that refresh token, I get access token with which I can use to access protected resources.

```
@Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware {

        private static final String ENV_OAUTH = "authentication.oauth.";
        private static final String PROP_CLIENTID = "clientid";
        private static final String PROP_SECRET = "secret";
        private static final String PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = "tokenValidityInSeconds";

        private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                    .inMemory()
                    .withClient(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_CLIENTID))
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .authorities(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN.name(), Authorities.ROLE_USER.name())
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .secret(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_SECRET))
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, Integer.class, 60))
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, Integer.class, 120));
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
            this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, ENV_OAUTH);
        }

    }

}
```

Note: I have used `JdbcTokenStore`, Please check above code. 
Whenever new access token is created/removed, I want to execute a method and want to run some code. How to do this? I am new to spring security and oauth, please suggest me the way to achieve this. Is there any filter or interceptor that I can add for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement your own [TokenStore](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenStore.html) or extends existing one (`InMemoryTokenStore,` `JdbcTokenStore`, `JwtTokenStore`) and add your code in `storeAccessToken` and `removeAccessToken`